# beginner reference type parameter confusion

Tags: c++

```
foo(int &bar)
{
    bar = 5;
}
```

The call to this function would be

```
int foobar = 2;

foo(foobar);
```

Am I right in thinking that the function parameter essentially 'gets' the memory address of the variable, but does not then have to be dereferenced in foo, and that I would be changing the original value of foobar? Before this I was under the Impression that you would have to pass in a memory address like this:

```
foo(&foobar);
```

and then use the variable inside foo like this:

```
*bar = 5;
```

Am I right in thinking that this is wrong? I think, like a lot of beginners, the confusion came from thinking that a reference was like a pointer in that it held a memory address, but it's never really a type is it? Just an operator.

Comment: `foo(&bar){}` is not a proper C++ function definition.

Comment: exact dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620604/difference-between-a-pointer-and-reference-parameter?

Comment: not quite, I was confused not about the difference between passing a pointer and passing as a reference, but rather how you then use the 'reference variable' so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References are usually implemented with underlying pointers (although that is not mandated by the standard), but they are a totally different beast than pointers. A reference is simply a new name or alias for an existing variable. When you do

```
void foo(int& bar)
{
    bar = 5;
}

int foobar = 2;
foo(foobar);
```

you are invoking `foo` to be evaluated with the variable `foobar`, so essentially `bar` within `foo` becames `foobar`. The usual compiler impementation for this is to actually implement this code like this:

```
void foo(int* bar)
{
    *bar = 5;
}

int foobar = 2;
foo(&foobar);
```

Comment: So is it more acceptable coding practice to just stick to pointer parameters?

Comment: @SirYakalot: No, if anything then the opposite. There is place for both in the language.

Answer (score 0):

If you did this:

```
void foo(int& bar) { bar = 6; }

int main() {
    int x = 3;
    foo(x);
}
```

x in main would equal 6.  This is because a reference/alias (a different name for the same variable) is passed into foo.  So, bar in function foo is the same variable as x in main, same memory location, and everything.

This is different from normal passing like this:

```
void foo(int bar) { bar = 6; }

int main() {
    int x = 3;
    foo(x);
}
```

where bar would be a new copy constructed value copied from x in main (note that copy constructor would better apply to a non-scalar type, but the idea is the same).

And lastly, if you did:

```
void foo(int* bar) { *bar = 6; }

int main() {
    int x = 3;
    foo(&x);
}
```

It would say "I want a pointer to an integer" for foo's parameter.  In main, we take the "Address of stack variable x" which is in essence the same thing as a pointer to x, and we pass it into bar.  Then dereferencing bar and assigning 6 to it would make x in main equal to 6 too :)