# Problems with functions parameters in pass by references in C++

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference

I am newbie in c++ and just learning it.
I have written the following code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
void first(int &x,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<x+i;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
void second(int *x,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<*x+i;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    int exm[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    first(exm[0],5);
    second(exm,5);

    return 0;
}
```

this program gives output correctly.but the problem is i don't understand the differences between using & and * in function parameters...
both are the techniques of passing arguments by references and when we pass by reference we just send the memory address...
but in function first when i tried to call the function as follows

```
first(exm,5);
```

function occurred an error.
why ?
but when i called the function as follows

```
first(exm[0],5);
```

it compiled properly and gave right output...but i know that the both calling is equivalent...
then why this error occured?
what is the difference between using & and * in function parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between a pointer and reference parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620604/difference-between-a-pointer-and-reference-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the variable `exm` is `int[5]`, which doesn't meet the signature of `first(int &x,int n)`.
But `int[N]` can be converted implicitly to `int*` that points to the first element of the array, hence `second(exm,5)` can compile.

> what is the difference between using & and * in function parameters?

It's the difference between a reference and a pointer.

There are lots of differences between them.
In this case, I think the biggest difference is whether it accepts NULL or not.

See:
- [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in)
- [Are there benefits of passing by pointer over passing by reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334856/are-there-benefits-of-passing-by-pointer-over-passing-by-reference-in-c)
- [difference between a pointer and reference parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620604/difference-between-a-pointer-and-reference-parameter)

Comment: thanks...but, in second(exm,5); doesn't exm passes the memory address of exm[0] ?

Comment: @KhairulBasar Yes, it does.