# Difference between using a reference and a pointer in function's arguments in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

I would like to know the difference between defining a function to take an argument to a reference of an object (case 1) and defining a function to take an argument to a pointer of an object (case 2).

Of course the way that you refer to the object itself differs, therefore I am asking about the different capabilities that one has by using the one or the other way when defining a function, as well as the context that the one or the other way of defining a function is used.

1) **Reference** to the object in the function's arguments

```
void function(T& t) { 

  // Procedure that might change 
  // the value of the object t.

  // t is the object

}

void main() {

  T object;
  function(object);

}
```

2) **Pointer** to the object in the function's arguments

```
void function(T* t) { 

  // procedure that might change 
  // the value of the object *t 

  // *t is the object
}

void main() {

  T object;
  function(&object);

}
```

Note: there are some questions that discuss the [difference between a pointer variable and a pointer variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in?rq=1), but this one examines the context of using the as function arguments.

Comment: You might also be interested in [difference between a pointer and reference parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/620604/865719)

Comment: They are basically the same except where they are different... Pointers can be NULL, references are not supposed to be. The parameters are treated differently when resolving overloaded functions.