# Passed by reference and passed by value

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int x[3] = {5,2,4}:
    swap(x,1,2);
}

void swap(int[] list, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = list[i];
    list[i] = list[j];
    list[j]= temp;
}
```

I am trying to figure out what this means, I get the passed by value. However I am not too familiar with pointers and value-results? Will some one explain or point me to an example dealing with C and the methodologies below?

1. Argument x is passed by value.
2. Argument x is passed by reference.
3. Argument x is passed by value-result.

Comment: C or C++? The answer is different for each. Passing by reference means "passing by reference type" in C++, while it means "using reference semantics" in C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass by pointer & Pass by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571078/pass-by-pointer-pass-by-reference)

Comment: You are passing a *pointer* to the first element of `x`.

Comment: Did you know that `list` is a class in the `std` namespace? This is *one* reason to *not* use `using namespace std;`: it avoids confusion and potential errors in code.

Comment: This isn't C++.  (Maybe C++/CLI, but that's still a different language.)

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile: `int[] list` should be `int list[]`, and `void main()` should be `int main()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is caused by the fact that *arrays do not exist in function argument lists*.

To elaborate:

```
void swap(int list[25], int i, int j)
void swap(int list[5], int i, int j)
void swap(int list[], int i, int j)
void swap(int* list, int i, int j)
```

are actually *the same function*.

Also:

```
int arr[30];
int* ptr = arr; // does the same as int* ptr = &arr[0]
```

These confusing semantics for C-style arrays was the reason why `std::array` was created.

And to answer your question:

1. You can't pass C-array by value.
2. You can pass C-array by reference (`void fun(int (&arr)[3])` is a function that takes three-element array by reference)
3. There is no pass by value-result in C++.

[Check this Stack Overflow question for more details about arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

[You should try this code on your codeblocks. i have explained all arguments in comment line to better understand.][1]

```
enter code here
```

https://ideone.com/17oQZV