# [C++]If passing by value creates a local copy, why does the original object get changed?

Tags: c++

I read on a similar question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269355/c-reasons-for-passing-objects-by-value) that passing by value will create a local copy of the object in your function. When I try to do this, my original object gets altered, but I do not want it to change.

The goal of this test was to try and pass an object, to alter it locally, but leaving the original untouched.

In the ObjectList header file:

```
int **board;
```

ObjectLise class containing a constructor and a print function:

```
ObjectList::ObjectList()
{
    board = new int*[9];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        board[i] = new int[9];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = 10;
        }
    }
}

void ObjectList::printB()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            cout << board[i][j] << ",";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

ChangeBoard class with function that gets passed an ObjectList.

```
void ChangeBoard::LetsChange(ObjectList layout)
{
    layout.board[0][0] = 99;
    layout.board[1][0] = 99;
    layout.board[2][0] = 99;
    layout.board[3][0] = 99;
    layout.board[4][0] = 99;
    layout.board[5][0] = 99;
}
```

In the main I create both objects and pass the ObjectList object to the LetsChange function to try and only alter the object locally, that is in the function only:

```
ObjectList object = ObjectList();

ChangeBoard change = ChangeBoard();

object.printB();

change.LetsChange(object);
cout << endl;

object.printB();
```

The output shows that the original object gets altered:

```
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,

99,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
99,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
99,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
99,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
99,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
99,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
```

Comment: The *object* isn't modified, but the data *pointed to* by `board` will be modified. I suggest you read about [the rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), and stop using pointers for arrays or vectors.

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve], but it looks like `ObjectList`'s copy-constructor is broken.

Comment: Voted to close as lacking reproducible example.

Comment: Assuming you haven't explicitly defined one, I think you need to look up copy constructor behaviour http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

Comment: As far as I understand you can only return pointers to arrays and not static arrays. This is why I chose to go with pointers.

Comment: @zeFrenchy. If I write a copy constructor that makes a deep copy of the board variable will this code produce what I initially wanted?

Comment: Should be ... see my answer below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit copy constructor will copy the content of the board pointer when copying the object ... so it will still point at the data from the original object. An ex[plicit copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) would probably need to allocate and copy the `board` array to obtain the behaviour you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Without a copy-constructor that actually copies the memory (or a suitable standard container) what happens when you pass the object by value is that the pointer member `board` is copied. The ***pointer*** is copied, not the data it points to. It's a so-called *shallow* copy, not a *deep* copy.

That means in the `ChangeBoard::LetsChange` function you have *two* objects in which the `board` members are both pointing to the same location. A quick printout of the `board` member or by just using a debugger you should have seen this very quickly.

In the function you modify the memory pointed to by this `board` pointer, not the data of the object itself. If you did e.g. `layout.board = new int*[9];` in the function, you would modify the actual member, and that change would not be reflected back in the calling function.

---

This copying of the *pointer* can lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) if you have a destructor that `delete[]` the memory pointed to by `board`. Because then you will free the memory for *both* objects, and when you later use the `board` member in the original object it will no longer point to allocated data.

This is the reason you need to consider [the rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

I recommend you stop using pointers and instead use either [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if the size is a compile-time constant, or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if the size is set at run-time.

Using either `std::array` or `std::vector` you can use [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) and not have to worry about handling your own memory, copying and deleting.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned your examples is not full

But let me try to clear a bit.
Your object `object` is passed by value, e.g. `LetsChange` function call makes a local copy of your object e.g. its members.

In your case, `board` which I suppose is a member of your class `ObjectList` will be copied but not the allocated memory, to which you point by `board`.

Therefore when you modify the memory it will technically "affect" the object you have.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not provide a copy constructor. The default copy constructor simply copies every member of the object (if this operation is define for every member of course). A copy of `board` is created. The copy of a pointer points to the same data as the original, though. So you are altering the original data which is technically not part of any object through a copy.

You could always resolve this by writing a copy constructor that copies the data being pointed to. A much better solution is to get rid of the `new` and corresponding `delete` statements and replace with a more appropriate alternative.

Most people would use `std::vector`. It will fix your default copy constructor and move constructor. It is also a variable length array which you might find useful.

If you need to enforce a static size, `std::array` is pretty much a safer, copyable C-style array. It doesn't decay to a pointer and it provides a proper copy constructor.

Lastly, if you need a static array but on the heap for whatever reason, `std::unique_ptr<>` and `std::shared_ptr<>` can hold an array. What they do is manage the lifetime of your objects internally. The difference is that `unique_ptr` only allows passing of ownership while `shared_ptr`s can point to the same object and they make sure to clean-up when the last pointer is destroyed or reset.