# How to use instance of one class in a method of another class?

Tags: c++, class, object, scope

I defined two classes **class A** and **class B**. They are completely independent.

Now I create `c` as instance of `class B` and `d` as instance of `class A`. Now I want to define the body of `functionOfA` that will perform operations on `c`:

```
class A {
public:
    functionOfA();
}

class B {
    ...
}

A::functionOFA()
{
    c.functionOfB();
}

main()
{
    A d;
    B c;
    d.functionOfA();
}
```

but the compiler gives me the following error: ***c is not declared in this scope***

Comment: Next time I suggest to use more meaningful names than `A` `B` `C` ~> I know this is just an example, it's not a real code, but still... any other type of example would do, animals etc.

Comment: sure. I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A::functionOfA()` definition needs to know what's `c` instance, you could pass in `B` instance:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    functionOfA(const B& b) const;
};

A::functionOFA(const B& b) const
{
    b.functionOfB();
}

A a;
B b;
a.functionOfA(b); // pass in B instance
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code (your `main`):

```
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a.functionOfA();
}
```

`b` is a local variable usable only within this scope. `b` represents an object with automatic storage duration that exists until the execution goes out of the scope (in this case: out of your `main`).

When you call the method `functionOfA`, although the object `b` still "lives", the `functionOfA` has no means of accessing this object ~> this method needs a reference to this object (or its copy) to use it:

```
class A {
public:
    void functionOfA(B& b) {
        /* b is now accessible here, this method can also change the object b */
    }
```

called in this manner:

```
A a;
B b;
a.functionOfA(b);
```

I recommend you to also have a look at these questions:
[How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2139224/1168156)
[Is it better in C++ to pass by value or pass by constant reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/270408/1168156)
[Are there benefits of passing by pointer over passing by reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/334856/1168156)

and some good book might be very helpful here too:
[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1168156)

Answer (score 0):

```
A::functionOFA()
{
    c.functionOfB();  //You cannot do this unless c is global
}
```

However in your case its in `main`

Use:

```
 B c;
void A::functionOfA()
{
    c.functionOfB();
}
```

OR

pass Object of B as an argument `functionOfA(const B& c)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how they are completely independent if 1 call method of another one. But You can pass `c` as argument.

```
class B
{public:
    functionOfB();
}

class A
{public:
    functionOfA(B /*or B& or const B&, learn about references*/ c);
    .....;
}



A::functionOFA(B c)
{
    c.functionOfB();
}

B::functionOfB()
{
  .....
}

main()
{
    A d;
    B c;
    d.functionOfA(c);
}
```

Comment: In d.functionOfA(), what should I write type of c?

Comment: you should just write `c`, fixed

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is that c is not accessible by any object of class A. To change this you can do either of two things: you can either give A a datamember of type B and use that or pass in an object of type B to function of A.

```
class A {
public:
    B objB;
    functionOfA();
}

class B {
    ...
}

A::functionOFA()
{
    objB.functionOfB();
}

main()
{
    A d;
    B c;
    d.objB = c;
    d.functionOfA();
}
```

OR (keeping them independent)

```
class A {
public:
    functionOfA(B& objB);
}

class B {
    ...
}

A::functionOFA(B& objB)
{
    objB.functionOfB();
}

main()
{
    A d;
    B c;
    d.functionOfA(c);
}
```

Check out dependency injection. I think you can make A sort of independent from B's type in the first scenario with that technique.