# Why and when to pass class types in C++ by pointer?

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers

Consider the following code:

```
class Abstract{
public:
    virtual void printStuff()=0;
};

class Derived: public Abstract{
public:
    void printStuff(){
        printf("Stuff\n");
    }
};
```

Now, let's say I want to create a function that uses the printStuff method from Abstract class. Before I learned that only one way is possible in C++, I thought that there would be two ways: the less obvious with pointers, and the more obvious, similar to what you would expect to do with ints, chars, etc.:

```
void ptr_function(Abstract* abs){ //non-obvious
    abs->printStuff();
}

void non_ptr_function(Abstract abs){ //obvious, analogous to, say, pow(a,b)
    abs.printStuff();
}
```

Now, I understand that the second one is forbidden in C++. However, I don't really understand the underlying reason for such design. Don't the above functions look identical, aside from the pointer vs. actal object being passed as an argument?

As a follow-up question: what is the preferred way to build classes that have to "contain" other, abstract, classes as one of the fields? If the answer to this question is also: "pointers", then am I missing something, or do I have to keep track of those objects' timelife myself (i.e. deleting them manually)? For non-abstract classes this is not an issue, as if I don't use pointers, then whenever that object gets out of scope, it gets automatically deleted (destructors called and so on). But if I have to use pointers, it looks like that micro-management takes a lot of unnecessary time and code.

**Is there any better way to approach this?**

Comment: References are the other way.

Comment: Smart pointers is another way. You get the freedom from pointers, but without the hassle of dealing with the lifetime itself. Have a look at std::unique_ptr<T> and std::smart_ptr<T>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there benefits of passing by pointer over passing by reference in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334856/are-there-benefits-of-passing-by-pointer-over-passing-by-reference-in-c)

Comment: Not a duplicate: the code above contrasts pass-by-pointer and pass-by-value. Pass-by-reference is a third option, ignored here. The suggested duplicate compares 1 and 3, ignoring option 2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't pass an abstract class by value because it can't be instantiated.  In most cases pass-by-value is the wrong thing to do anyway (or at least the non-optimal).  What you're looking for is pass by reference:

```
void ref_function(Abstract & abs)
{
    abs.printStuff();
}
```

When you pass by reference any modifications made to `abs` inside `ref_function` are applied to the same instance that exists outside of the function.  Ideally in your test case, you'd want to pass the object as `const Abstract & abs` which will prevent any changes from being made to the object.  In your example though, you would need to mark `printStuff` as const to denote that it will not change the object it's invoked on - the signature would change to `virtual void printStuff() const`

In response to your other question about how ownership of abstract classes should work.. remember that you can't actually have an instance of an abstract class, so what you're talking about is holding a pointer to some derived object via a handle to its abstract base class.  You probably want to use std::unique_ptr for this as it will properly delete the owned object when your class is destroyed.

```
class Abstract
{
    public:
        virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Abstract
{
    public:
        virtual void Foo() override {}
};

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Abstract> myObject;
};

MyClass::MyClass() : myObject(std::make_unique<Derived>())
{
}
```

Comment: And, in this case, `const` reference

Comment: I didn't use a const ref because `printStuff()` isn't a const method - presumably that's just an oversight on OP's part though.

Comment: And even though you can pass a non-abstract base class by value, do realize that you will get a **sliced copy** of the actual object. However, the claim here is too strong. Pass by value is the right thing to do for objects with value-behavior such as `int` and `std::complex<double>`. Every 5 has the value 5, after all.

Comment: Thank you for your input. References really look like a way to go - in the first case I mentioned anyway (functions). But there is still the second issue, with abstract class objects being fields in other classes. From the brief skim over references' properties I just did, it seems that they cannot be left uninitialized. What is the correct way to initialize such fields, and where (constructor?) is the best place to do it?

Comment: @MSalters Good point regarding both the sliced copy problem - that can be a very subtle bug to C++ newcomers.  I feel like it's better to overstate the case for pass-by-reference to newcomers since the lesson is more likely to stick that way.  You're right, of course, that pass-by-value can often be the right thing to do for objects that are meant to be used that way.

Comment: @akrasuski1 I edited my answer to address the other part of your question.

Comment: There's two things I'd consider expanding the answer to mention:
1) It's important to realize when you pass by reference that the object in the function scope is the same as the one passed in, and changes will be reflected. So the issue of const correctness is very important. The print function should probably be marked const, and the function should accept const reference.
2) Sometimes you will want to pass a pointer to Base rather than reference to Base. Primarily this occurs when it is possible that you are dealing with a non-object, a pointer can be nullptr, a reference cannot.

Comment: After a second thought, I noticed that those references, I was so enthusiastic about a moment ago, are not that good after all. There are isses with it, such as impossibility to declare an array of references - so I can't write code that for example assigns to an array of Abstract references one of two derived class objects a random.

Comment: @akrasuski1 Try not to think about it as whether references are *good* or not - first understand them and then look at whether or not they're the correct tool for the job you're trying to do.  In C++, references cannot be reseated - meaning for their entire lifetime they always refer to one thing and one thing only.

Comment: @akrasuski1 In your example case, you probably want either an `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr<Abstract>` (if the class is to own the objects) or an `std::vector` of `std::weak_ptr<Abstract>` if the class should not have any ownership over them.  In the latter case something else must be responsible for owning the `std::shared_ptr<Abstract>`.

Comment: @mbgda Thanks for introducing the concept of new types of pointers (well, they are 3 years old now). Now I'm looking at the docs, which are a lot longer for those. Perhaps you know a good starter guide for when to use which type of pointer?

Comment: @akrasuski1 What you really want is a thorough and up-to-date text book on C++.  However, as a temporary solution here is a decent write-up about smart pointers from a U of M professor: http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/C++11_smart_ptrs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There are actually five different possibilities to pass an object to a function:

```
//Function declarations
void passByValue(Derived o);    //Not possible with an abstract class.
void passByReference(Abstract& o);
void passByConstReference(const Abstract& o);
void passByPointer(Abstract* o);
void passByConstPointer(const Abstract* o);

//Function calls
Derived o;
passByValue(o);
passByReference(o);      //May change o!
passByConstReference(o);
passByPointer(&o);       //May change o.
passByConstPointer(&o);
```

Because it is not visible from the call of `passByReference(o)` that the call may modify the variable `o`, I never use pass-by-reference. I always use either pass-by-const-reference or pass-by-pointer.

However, many C++ programmers today generally abhor the use of pointers because they don't play well with smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr<>` and `std::shared_ptr<>`. If you manage your objects with these smart pointers, you must always pass the smart pointer instead of a naked pointer/reference, usually by const-reference:

```
void passBySmartPointer(const std::shared_ptr<Abstract>& o);
void passConstBySmartPointer(const std::shared_ptr<const Abstract>& o);
```

With this approach, you never see a naked pointer in your code...

(The reason for the need to pass the smart pointer is that the chain of smart pointers must not be broken: If you convert a smart pointer to a naked pointer, and then back to a smart pointer, the second smart pointer does not know about the first, and you'll get trouble. There are other means to avoid this, but this is way beyond the scope of this answer.)

Comment: You're missing `Derived &&`, so it's actually six. But you can't pass your example `o` object to that. Also, it's quite rare to pass a `const std::shared_ptr<Abstract>&`; what would you do with that pointer which you can't do with just a `const Abstract&` ?

Comment: @MSalters I can initialize another `std::shared_ptr<Abstract>` from a `const std::shared_ptr<Abstract>&` which cannot (read: must not) be done from an `Abstract&` (that's the corresponding non-smart-pointer type: the only thing that's const in `const std::shared_ptr<Abstract>&` is the smart pointer itself). And yes, C++ has become even more baroque since C++11 ;-) but I think, r-value references are beyond the scope of this question. That's an optimization for people who are already deep into C++, not something for people who are just beginning with C++.