# What is the difference between * and & in function parameters?

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, reference, dereference

I have seen something in this form:

```
void function( A_struct &var ) {
   var.field0 = 0;
   // ...
}
```

Since there is `&` before `var`, I thought that `var` is a pointer. But in the body, instead of writing `var->field0`, `var.field0` is written. So, my questions are:

1. Isn't `var` a pointer?
2. What is the difference between writing `A_struct &var` and `A_struct *var` in function parameter?

Comment: This is C++ reference

Comment: This is illegal in C. You must be looking at C++ code and not realize it.

Comment: Then what is their difference in C++?

Comment: You can think of a reference as `an automatically dereferenced constant pointer`, so it almost looks like the copy of variable itself. You can read more about reference in any basic C++ book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is actually related to `C++`

`void function(A_struct &var)` is not valid for `C` because in `C` it is used to get an address of a variable. In `C++` it is a type of variable which is known as `reference`. You can see an example of it in [here](http://www.hermetic.ch/cfunlib/ast_amp2.htm)

`void function(A_struct *var)` is allowed in `C` and `C++`, because is a pointer which holds the address of `A_struct` type variable's address.

Answer (score 4):

A syntax like `A_struct &var` is not valid in context of `C`.

It is used in case of `C++` to denote *pass-by-reference*.

Related: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/334856/2173917) and related answers for more details.