# How can I avoid circular dependencies in a header only library?

Tags: c++, header-files

I am a developing a C++ header only library.

There are several parts of the code which follow this pattern:

**holder.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "sub.h"

struct Holder
{
    void f();
    Sub s;
};
```

**sub.h**

```
#pragma once

struct Holder;

struct Sub
{
   void g(Holder& h);
};

#include "sub.ipp"
```

**sub.ipp**

```
#include "holder.h"

inline void Sub::g(Holder& h)
{
    h.f();
}
```

*sub.h* avoids the circular dependency on *Holder* using forward declaration. However, in *holder.h* as the *Holder* class contains a *Sub* member it needs to see the full declaration of *Sub* in *sub.h*. *sub.h*, however, pulls in the implementation in *sub.ipp* which can't be instantiated yet as it needs the definition of *Holder* and we are already inside *holder.h* so we can't include it again.

As I user of any of these headers I would like to only have to include the correct *.h* file and not have to worry about manually including the correct *.ipp* files in strange places.

What is the standard solution to this?

Comment: With include guards, you might put some code outside the guards. Not possible with `#pragma once`...

Comment: The solution you've shown here is the one of the two I use.  The other is assuming the two classes are really part of the same component because they go hand-in-hand, and therefore they belong together in the same header file.

Comment: You may need to pass `Holder` as a (smart) pointer as opposed to a reference.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334856/are-there-benefits-of-passing-by-pointer-over-passing-by-reference-in-c

Comment: @Den-Jason: That doesn't change dependencies concern. Don't have to bother with `nullptr` currently, contrary to pointers.

Comment: including separate headers with method impls makes the most sense with templates. Safe to assume that `Sub` is actually a template class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> struct Sub
> {
>    void g(Holder& h);
> };
>
> void Sub::g(Holder& h)
> {
>     h.f();
> }
> ```

Non-inline functions won't work well in header-only libraries, because the headers are typically included into more than one translation unit. You should use inline functions instead.

---

> How can I avoid circular dependencies in a header only library?

You'll have to separate the definition of the functions from the definition of the class. I mean, they are in separate files already, but the header defining the class cannot include the function definitions. That allows breaking the dependency cycle.

This may be a matter of taste, but I also dislike "ipp" headers that don't work standalone.

Example:

**detail/holder_class_only.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "detail/sub_class_only.h"
struct Holder
{
    inline void f(); // note inline
    Sub s;
};
```

**detail/sub_class_only.h**

```
#pragma once
struct Holder;
struct Sub
{
   inline void g(Holder& h); // note inline
};
```

**detail/holder_functions.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "detail/holder_class_only.h"
void Holder::f()
{
}
#include "detail/sub_functions.h"
```

**detail/sub_functions.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "detail/sub_class_only.h"
#include "holder.h"
void Sub::g(Holder& h)
{
    h.f();
}
```

**sub.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "detail/sub_class_only.h"
#include "detail/sub_functions.h"
```

**holder.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "detail/holder_class_only.h"
#include "detail/holder_functions.h"
```

Note: Unstested, may contain bugs.

Comment: `#include "detail/sub_functions.h"` seems unneeded *"holder_functions.h"*

Comment: @Jarod42 `seems unneeded "holder_functions.h"` It's there just in case, because when `"detail/sub_class_only.h"` is included, its functions may be called which will result in ODR violation (NDR) if  `"detail/sub_functions.h"` isn't included. The "class_only" headers are a bit fragile because of that, but I see no reason to have that fragility in "functions" headers.

Comment: @Jarod42 `inline should go in definition.` Why? `No needs in declaration` On the other hand, no needs in definition, when it's in the declaration.

Comment: The question makes a lot more sense if you assume `Sub` is a template class. Then extracting it's methods to a separate header is _virtually required_.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent some time figuring this out, here is a technique expanded from @eerorika 's answer.

There are two problematic cases:

- Case 1: A contains B, B uses A
- Case 2: A uses B, B uses A

If your structs don't fall under any of these cases, you can type out both the declaration and the implementation in the same header file.

For both case 1 and 2, my technique is to split the file into .hpp, .hppdecl and .hppimpl.

*Note:*

- *Storage of B* (pointer) counts as "uses" and not "contains"*;
- *Inheritance counts as "contains"*;
- *Templating can be "uses", "contains", or neither if it is only used for type safety*;

---

**A.hpp:**

- Includes A.hppdecl first.
- Includes A.hppimpl second.

**A.hppdecl:** *(contains declarations)*

- If A contains B (case 1), include the B.hppdecl.
- If A uses B (case 2), forward declare.

**A.hppimpl:** *(contains implementations)*

- Includes A.hppdecl first.
- If A contains B (case 1), include the B.hppimpl.
- If A uses B (case 2), include the B.hppdecl and the B.hppimpl.

And, do the same for B's files.

---

Why? Because you must respect the following restrictions/guidelines:

- If A contains B and B uses A (case 1), B's declaration and implementation must be split (because Adecl must include Bdecl, and Bimpl must include Adecl)
- If a declaration is included, its corresponding implementation must be guaranteed to be included at some point
- Declarations must precede their own implementation, and can precede every other implementation